# Apex class - condition evaluating as null

Tags: apex

The cases I'm triggering definitely have Account populated. But the code is processing as if Account is null.

This is the line that is processing as if cl.Account is null. But it isn't and will never be.  IF(cl.Product__c!=null && cl.Account!=null)

Any ideas?

Here is the relevant lines of my class/method called by a trigger that passes the trigger.new list.

```
public class CaseTeams{
    Public List<Case> lstNewCases = new List<Case>();
    public void TeamLoading() {

        String RoleNo;
        String Role;
        String Name;
        String UserId;
        String TeamRole;

        List<Account> CaseAccounts = new List<Account>();
        For(Case cl: lstNewCases){CaseAccounts.add(cl.Account);}

        Map<Id,User> mapCaseUsers = new Map<Id,User>();
        Map<Id,Product2> mapCaseProduct = new Map<Id,Product2>();
        Map<Id,Account> mapCaseAccount = new Map<Id,Account>();

        List<User> users = new List<User>([SELECT Id, Name, Manager_Name__c FROM User WHERE IsActive = TRUE]);
        List<Product2> products = new List<Product2>([SELECT Id,PO1_Role__c FROM Product2]);
        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>([SELECT Id,Role_01__c,User_Id_01__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN: CaseAccounts]);

        For(User ul: users){mapCaseUsers.put(ul.id,ul);}
        For(Product2 pl: products){mapCaseProduct.put(pl.id,pl);}
        For(Account al: accounts){mapCaseAccount.put(al.id,al);}

        IF(lstNewCases.size()>0){
            For(Case cl : lstNewCases){
                IF(cl.Product__c!=null && cl.Account!=null){     
                    IF(cl.Owner_Ex__c=='ON'){UserId=cl.OwnerId;TeamRole=mapCaseUsers.get(cl.OwnerId).Name;}
                    ELSE{
                        IF(mapCaseProduct.get(cl.Id).PO1_Role__c==null){UserId='00G50000001BwvX';TeamRole='Leasestar';}
                        ELSE{
                            RoleNo=mapCaseProduct.get(cl.Product__c).PO1_Role__c.left(2);
                            Role=mapCaseProduct.get(cl.Product__c).PO1_Role__c.substringafter('-');
                            Name=mapCaseAccount.get(cl.AccountId).Role_01__c;
                            UserId=mapCaseAccount.get(cl.AccountId).User_Id_01__c; 
                            TeamRole=Name+' ['+Role+']';
                        }
                    }
                    cl.OwnerId=UserId;
                    cl.Implementation_Owner__c=UserId;
                    cl.TeamRole1__c=TeamRole;
                    RoleNo=null;
                    UserId=null;
                    Name=null;
                    TeamRole=null;
                    Role=null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The expression is also checking cl.Product__c, if this is null the expression will return false regardless as to the value of cl.Account__c. For this expression to return true, both have to contain values.

Comment: Yes sorry - product is also always populated. If either is null - it shouldn't run.

But the issue is that my test cases all definitely have both populated.

Comment: Further testing has determined that none of the case fields are found when referenced in the forloop. Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 1):

You're checking the *relationship*, which will be null unless you query for it. Consider these three queries:

```
Case a = [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Case WHERE AccountId != NULL LIMIT 1];
Case b = [SELECT Id, Account.Name, Account.Id FROM Case WHERE AccountId != NULL LIMIT 1];
Case c = [SELECT Id, Account.Name, Account.Id, AccountId FROM Case WHERE AccountId != NULL LIMIT 1];
```

The following information is true:

```
System.assertEquals(null, a.Account);
System.assertNotEquals(null, a.AccountId);
System.assertEquals(null, b.AccountId);
System.assertNotEquals(null, b.Account);
System.assertNotEquals(null, c.Account);
System.assertNotEquals(null, c.AccountId);
```

Here, `a.account` is null, even though there is clearly an account ID. That's because `a.account` refers to an SObject that houses related data. No data is queried, so it is null. Conversely, `b.account` is not null, because we asked for `b.Account.Name`, but not `b.AccountId`, and so `b.AccountId` is null, even though there is clearly an associated account (because `b.Account` is not null).

In summary, use the non-ID version of a field if you mean to check related data, or the ID version of a field if you simply want the ID. Also note that `b.AccountId` does not equal `b.Account.Id`; because we didn't ask for `b.AccountId`, we didn't get that back in the query, while `c.Account.Id` does equal `c.AccountId`, because we explicitly queried both.

Comment: Added this list query: List<Case> cases = new List<Case>([SELECT Id, XLS01__c,OwnerId,IsClosed,Owner_Ex__c,Account.Id,Product__r.Id FROM Case WHERE Id IN: lstNewCases]);   Account is now not null. But anytime I reference a case field - it gets a null pointer error. Not sure what you mean by use the non-id version.

Comment: Case.Account is an SObject (the non-ID version), while Case.AccountId is an Id (the ID version). All standard "ID" fields follow this practice: Product2 vs Product2Id, Account vs AccountId, Contact vs ContactId, etc. Custom fields use Field__r as the "non-ID version," and "Field__c" as the "ID version." In your code, you use cl.Product__c, which means you need to query Product__c, not Product__r.Id; they are not the same object.